# How does python synchronize the following code?

Tags: python, multithreading

In the following code I start two threads, each gets the same counter as a parameter and I start them simultaneously. I expect the output to be chaotic but it seems to be synchronized. Why is that so?

```
 import threading


class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0

    def increment(self):
        self.i += 1

    def get_i(self):
        return self.i


class UnsynchronizedThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, counter: Counter):
        super().__init__()
        self.counter = counter

    def run(self) -> None:
        for i in range(100):
            self.counter.increment()
            print(f"{threading.get_ident()} - {self.counter.get_i()}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    counter1 = Counter()
    thread1 = UnsynchronizedThread(counter1)
    thread2 = UnsynchronizedThread(counter1)
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
```

And this is the output

```
140507778238208 - 1
140507778238208 - 2
140507778238208 - 3
140507769845504 - 4
140507769845504 - 5
140507769845504 - 6
140507769845504 - 7
140507769845504 - 8
140507769845504 - 9
140507769845504 - 10
140507769845504 - 11
...
```

Comment: CPython uses the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) to effectively synchronize every statement.

Comment: Is it possible to disable GIL?

Comment: I think "seems" is the operative word here. Nothing is synchronized; it just takes so little time for `Counter.increment` to run that triggering a race condition is difficult.

Comment: You don’t want to/can’t disable the GIL in cPython - it’s integral to the implementation of cPython.

Comment: Not only could a thread be suspended between `self.counter.increment()` and `self.counter.get_i()`, but a thread might even be interrupted while `self.i += 1` (a non-atomic operation) is executing. This means two or more threads could increment the value between the first thread adding 1 to `self.i` and the first thread storing the result back to `self.i`, resulting the counter being *decremented*.